# What's the usage of `Data center bridging`?

Tags: networking, sdn

```
show dcb app
show clock
Privileged Mode
#
Displays DCB (Data center bridging) application data.
Command Syntax
Command Modes Syntax Description
Command Default Examples
show dcb app {local status|map}|{remote status|map}|status|map
This command has no default settings.
#show clock
05:59:29.770072 None 2000-01-02
1.0.1
Privileged Mode
#
local
remote
status
map
This command has no default settings.
#show dcb app map
#show dcb app status
#show dcb app local map
```

in a SuperMicro MBM-XEM, there is dcb concept, what's the meaning of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](ftp://supermicro.com/ISO_Extracted/CDR-X9_1.30_for_Intel_X9_platform/Broadcom/Manuals/English/dcb.htm) can explain it better than we can:

> Data Center Bridging (DCB) is a collection of IEEE specified standard
>   extensions to Ethernet to provide lossless data delivery, low latency,
>   and standards-based bandwidth sharing of data center physical links.
>   DCB supports storage, management, computing, and communications
>   fabrics onto a single physical fabric that is simpler to deploy,
>   upgrade, and maintain than in standard Ethernet networks. DCB has a
>   standards-based bandwidth sharing at its core, allowing multiple
>   fabrics to coexist on the same physical fabric. The various
>   capabilities of DCB allow for LAN traffic (large number of flows and
>   not latency-sensitive), SAN traffic (large packet sizes and requires
>   lossless performance), and IPC (latency-sensitive messages) to
>   bandwidth share the same physical converged connection and achieve the
>   desired individual traffic performance.
>
> DCB includes the following capabilities:
>
> Enhanced Transmission Selection (ETS)
>
> Priority-based Flow Control (PFC)
>
> Data Center Bridging Capability eXchange Protocol (DCBX)

Comment: How to understand the ` DCB has a standards-based bandwidth sharing at its core, allowing multiple fabrics to coexist on the same physical fabric`?